# Is there a way to get LatLng of a street within particular city using Google Geocoder?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am writing an application which requires to put a marker on a street within one city. I've added an input for searching this particular street (to simplify the process and not have to drag and locate the street manually).

So, entering "[Street name], [City]" works as expected and locates the street perfectly. However enetering only "[Street name]" centers map on the street but in another city.

Is there a way to tell Geocoder to search in a particular city?

In the end I can manually add ", [City]" to the request but I'm wondering if it's possible through the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the geocoder to bias towards a particular area:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingViewports

Note: this is not entirely foolproof: it *biases*, it doesn't *restrict*. So if you look for "Downing Street" in a tiny village it may well find Downing Street in London anyway.

The only foolproof way is to force the city into the address.